# suggestions for tools and techniques to work efficiently with Magento for a beginner

Tags: magento

**Magento:** locating associated files and classes by just viewing the template file(.phtml) in magento is right now a nightmare to me .

Since, i am a new programmer to any framework and my first framework is Magento,

**1** . Can any one please **suggest me techniques, tools or tutorials to easily track files and classes associated to a template file in Magento**?
while suggesting please suggest something of great help to a complete beginner .. plzz.

**2** and also suggest me with the right way to learn Magento framework .(i am finding it really very confusing)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Every template file has a block class associated with it. The block class does the logic and the template is used for rendering. If you have a template like catalog/product/view.phtml you will find a block class for it in mage/catalog/block/product/view.php. Magento is not learnt overnight. The layout xml files describe what blocks are used for which templates. It takes a long time to get to know how it all fits together and how to extend it properly etc. Best thing is start developing with it and do one thing at a time until you hit that eureka moment.

Comment: ohh thanks for stating that eureka moment.. :) really waiting for that to come.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can learn many good techinques from magento Forum.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards
For extension development this book is awesome
http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Magento-Extension-Developers-Guide-v1.0.pdf
```

Comment: thanks Rizwan, i will surely go throug the book, i am badly in need of anything that really helps.

Comment: Best way to learn download Magento and start development :) You can learn many things from Google during development period.